# Difference between custom merge and std::inplace_merge

Tags: c++

I have a function which works when I use the following implementation of merge:

```
void merge(vector<int>& A, int start, int mid, int end)
{
    int n1 = (mid - start + 1);
    int n2 = (end - mid);
    int L[n1], R[n2];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = A[start + i];
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = A[mid + 1 + j];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (int k = start; k <= end; k++) {
        if (j >= n2 || (i < n1 && L[i] <= R[j]))
            A[k] = L[i++];
        else
            A[k] = R[j++];
    }
}
```

and call it using `merge(A, start, mid, end);`.

However when I instead use `std::inplace_merge(A.begin() + start, A.begin() + mid, A.begin() + end);` I get incorrect results.

What is the difference between these two? I expected them to be the same

Comment: Please edit your question top contain [mcve] and add sample data which you think leads to wrong result and why.

Comment: One possible problem is your code treats `mid` as part of the left range, and `end` is included in the right (`[start,mid]` and `[mid+1,end]` inclusive), while [`inplace_merge`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge) has `mid` as the start of the right range and `end` is excluded (`[start,mid) and `[mid,end)`).